# Regex to match only first vowel and include it in a match

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to find the first match of the vowel in the string and then partition a string in ruby but I'm not getting correct results.

The thing I tried was

```
"rodio".partition(/[(?=aeiouAEIOU)].*/).reject(&:empty?)
```

but I get back `["r", "odio"]`. For any word I throw, I'm getting back the part without vowel and part with, but I need the part without the vowel to include it. So it should be

`["ro", "dio"]`.

`celery` should be `["ce", "lery"]` not `["c", "elery"]` etc.

What am I missing? I'm trying everything but I have no idea how to write it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a positive lookbehind and a `split` with `2` limit argument:

```
.split(/(?<=[aeiou])/i, 2)
```

See the [online Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/WZQExx)

The `(?<=[aeiou])` pattern is a *positive lookbehind* that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `a`, `e`, `i`, `o` or `u` (case insensitive matching is enabled with `/i` modifier). `2` *limit* argument makes the engine split the string into 2 parts only, so it will split only once at the first match.

You may surely use the same pattern with `.partition`:

```
.partition(/(?<=[aeiou])/i).reject(&:empty?)
```

Comment: This works. Thanks! I've been testing various regexes for about an hour now, looks so simple...

Comment: Readers, note: `"try".split(/(?<=[aeiou])/i, 2) #=> ["try"]`, as desired.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to use any lookaround to do that, a non-greedy quantifier suffices:

```
"rodio".partition(/.*?[aeiou]/i).reject(&:empty?)
```

Or better, using a negated character class:

```
"rodio".partition(/[^aeiou]*./i).reject(&:empty?)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a positive look-behind: `"rodio".partition(/(?<=[aeiou])/i).reject(&:empty?)`

Answer (score 1):

One could use [String#index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-index) to find the location of the first vowel, then [String#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) ("slice").

```
str = "their"
i = str.index /[aeiou]/i
  #=> 2
i.nil? ? str : [str[0..i], str[i+1..-1]]
  #=> ["the", "ir"]

str = "tryst"
i = str.index /[aeiou]/i
  #=> nil
i.nil? ? str : [str[0..i], str[i+1..-1]]
  #=> "tryst"
```